# Marshmallow: How to handle undeclared fields?

Tags: python, validation, schema, deserialization, marshmallow

I am trying to validate a dict which contains stringified integers as keys. These ints are arbitrary numerical IDs, and out of my control.

How could I declare this in a schema?

Maybe there's a way to declare a default schema which I could use as a catch-all?

Thanks.

http://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: You can get all of the keys of the dict with dict.keys() and then iterate over all of them with something like `for k in d.keys(): validate k and d[k]`

Answer (score 0):

The way I prefer, use a map instead of `if statement`:

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    dictionary[
        {
         "True": str(key), 
          "False": <build a random key> 
        }.get(str(isinstance(key, int)))
     ] = value
```

Note: works only on Python3+